# map is not a function in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

This block of code caused error of map is not a function

```
 {data && (data.devices || {}).map((obj, i) => 
    <div>{obj.name}</div>
 )}
```

I just don't get it, I already did `data &&` to check data is defined else keep the map. And also `data.devices || {}` to check if the devices property is there or not.

I `console.log(data.devices)` is return undefined but it should fallback to an object right? why is it still breaking?

Comment: `.map` is a function on arrays, not objects. Change it to `data.devices || []`

Comment: @NicholasTower tried that, it still the same, it says `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Originally you said the error was `map is not a function`. You say that after the change it is "still the same", but that's it's `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Can you clarify whether the error has changed or not?

Comment: Problem is `data && (data.devices || {})` or `data && (data.devices || [])` returns null if data is null. That is the reason you are getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native `.map` to `{}`, so replace `data.devices || {}` to `data.devices || []`

```
{(data && data.devices || []).map((obj, i) => 
    <div>{obj.name}</div>
)}
```

Comment: will this work is the data doesn't even have a property called `devices`?

Comment: yes, in that case, the map will run on an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `map` is not a function because when `data.devices` is empty, the default value is an empty object hence `map` is not a function of an object. Take this for example:

```js
// simulate scenarios
const data00 = undefined;
const data01 = {};
const data02 = { devices: null };
const data03 = { devices: [] };
const data04 = { devices: [{ name: 'device01' }, { name: 'device02' }] }


class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.load(data00)}
        {this.load(data01)}
        {this.load(data02)}
        {this.load(data03)}
        {this.load(data04)}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  /**
   * Loads data and renders the devices if there's any
   */
  load(data) {
    return (!!data && data.devices || []).map((obj, i) => 
       <div key={i}>{obj.name}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"/>
```

As you can see, only `data04`'s devices will be rendered.