# How do I correctly iterate through an object in render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have an object that I'm trying to iterate through:

```
this.props.recentMessages = {
    '4383456789': {
          'number': '4383456789',
          'created': 1531142643,
          'text': "Hello World"
     },
    '5141234567': {
          'number': '5141234567'
          'created': 1531173846
          'text': "This is the second text"
     }
}
```

But the problem I get right now is that it says that `this.props.recentMessages.map is not a function` so I'm not sure how I would correct iterate through as I was able to successfully iterate through an array of strings earlier. I want to check that `this.props.recentMessages` exist first before I iterate through it.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="menu-tab">
      <LeftNav className="chat-left-nav">
        {this.props.recentMessages
          ? this.props.recentMessages.map(function(thread, index) {
              <LeftNavSC.Item>
                <span key={index} className="contact-name">
                  {thread.number}
                </span>
                <br />
              </LeftNavSC.Item>;
            })
          : ""}
      </LeftNav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You aren't telling it to return the JSX in the map. Try adding `return <LeftNavSc.Item>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [map is not a function in jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481327/map-is-not-a-function-in-jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over an object with `map` the same way you do with an array. You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of all the keys in the object, and `map` over that:

```
render() {
  const { recentMessages } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className="menu-tab">
      <LeftNav className="chat-left-nav">
        {recentMessages &&
          Object.keys(recentMessages).map(key => (
            <LeftNavSC.Item key={key}>
              <span className="contact-name">
                {recentMessages[key].number}
              </span>
              <br />
            </LeftNavSC.Item>
          ))}
      </LeftNav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects in JavaScript don't come with `map` function but you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key-value pairs which you can iterate.

```
{Object.entries(this.props.recentMessages).map(([key, thread]) => {
  <LeftNavSC.Item>
    <span key={key} className="contact-name">
      {thread.number}
    </span>
    <br />
  </LeftNavSC.Item>;
})}
```

Down below you can see what `Object.entries` returns from your sample data:

```js
const entries = Object.entries({
  '4383456789': {
    'number': '4383456789',
    'created': 1531142643,
    'text': "Hello World"
   },
  '5141234567': {
    'number': '5141234567',
    'created': 1531173846,
    'text': "This is the second text"
   }
})

console.log(entries)
```

In order to prevent getting errors while iterating non-existing collection you can use short-circuiting `&&` operator or use the or operator `||` to provide a default value of an empty object to iterate empty collection which will both result in empty views:

```
this.props.recentMessages && Object.entries(this.props.recentMessages).map(...)
```

Or with default value:

```
Object.entries(this.props.recentMessages || {}).map(...)
```